# AWS Amplify tag based deployment using Github

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-amplify

I want to start the **AWS Amplify build** once I push some **git tag**. Is there any way to trigger the build this way?

Just like we can do through Github Workflows, in which we used to specify the events that are going to trigger the specific jobs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like tags are not supported yet based on this GH issue

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/614

You can try though specifying it via same pattern as described here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/pattern-based-feature-branch-deployments.html

and test whether it would work

For tag it should be like `refs/tags/v*` (e.g. `v1.2.3` tag) instead of `refs/heads/release*` for branches (e.g. `release-20220-12` branch)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this and one option would be to just ditch the amplify CI/CD and Git repo connection [use a manually deployed app instead](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/manual-deploys.html).

You would create an Amplify App that is not connected to a Git provider, and then build your app using the CI/CD process of your choice (i.e. Github Actions). Then use the following AWS cli calls to deploy:

- [create-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/amplify/create-deployment.html)
- [start-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/amplify/start-deployment.html)

This way you can exactly control from your CI/CD of your choice when to deploy what.

Nevermind that, you can actually just specify the tag value for the branch name and it will work as expected. So you can just add e.g. `v1-0-0` and it will take the tag ref.